# How to customize automatic row labels in seaborn FacetGrid? How to get single xlabel and ylable for the whole figure?

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to know how to customize the row labels of the FacetGrid. There is an automatic value 0.0, 0.1 and so on to be changed into "ratio <5%", "ratio <10%", ....

Also would like to know how to have a single xlabel and ylabel (not repeated to each facet of  the grid).

See Python image and R image.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, 
                  col="chlorides_rounded", 
                  height=3.3, 
                  row='ratio_sulfur.dioxide_rounded',
                  margin_titles=True,
                  hue='quality_bucket', 
                  hue_order=['High', 'Medium', 'Low'],palette = 'RdYlGn_r')

g = (g.map(plt.scatter, "density", "alcohol", **kws).add_legend(markerscale=2))
```

[image: Python image]

[image: R image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution which is quite ugly, but I did not receive other ones!

```
ratio_labels =  ["","","",
             "ratio <5%",
             "","","",
             "ratio < 15%",
             "","","",
             "ratio <25%",
             "","","",
             "ratio < 35%",
             "","","",
             "ratio <45%",
             "","","",
             "ratio < 55%",
             "","","",
             "ratio <65%",
             "","","",
             "ratio < 75%"]

for i, ax in enumerate(g.axes.flat):
    plt.setp(ax.texts, text=ratio_labels[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone else can come up with an easier solution, my solution is not the prettiest but can give you what you asked for. And since you did not share your data I used the toy dataset that came with `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns

att = sns.load_dataset("attention")
g = sns.FacetGrid(att, col="subject", col_wrap=5, height=1.5)
g = g.map(plt.plot, "solutions", "score", marker=".")

#this surpresses the x- and y-labels on each axes of the bottom/leftmost column
g.set_axis_labels('', '') 

# overall ylabel
g.fig.text(x=0, y=0.5, 
           verticalalignment='center', #make sure it's aligned at center vertically
           s='Alcohol % per volume', #this is the text in the ylabel
           size=16, #customize the fontsize if you will
           rotation=90) #vertical text

#overall xlabel
g.fig.text(x=0.5, y=0, 
           horizontalalignment='center', #make sure it's aligned at center horizontally
           s='Density $g/cm^3$', #this is the text in the xlabel
           size=16)
```

Comment: Thanks. This **perfectly works** and answers the second question.  What about the **first question** about the row labels?

Comment: @hganger Adding the x-label is syntactically similar to adding the y-label. I have added the part in the answer.

Comment: Thank you again. However my question was not clear enough. Of course I did it for x as for y axis. But my question was about the labels of the facetgrid row values. In R I can change them as you can see (0.0 is "ratio <5%" and so on) but in Python how to do the same?